# XQuery - Get only the Query Value

Tags: xml, xquery, where-clause

I'm very new at XQUERY...

I've an element from a XML file like this:

```
 <element field="SQL" name="QUERY" value="INSERT INTO tableB SELECT * FROM tableA;"/>
```

And I'm using XQuery in order to get the queries that have INSERT INTO. So from my XML file I've to receive this this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
```

I am trying with this code to get that:

```
for $x in doc("C:\XXXXX.item")
where matches($x, "INSERT INTO$") = true()
return $x/element
```

But it doesn't give me any result :(

How can I get the desire result?

Many thanks

Comment: Mads Hansen's answer is correct but you also need to fix your REGEX. $ is the end of line anchor, not a wildcard.

Comment: That's correct! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code, your `$x` is a sequence of one document, and your WHERE clause is evaluating whether the computed text value of that document (which does not include attribute values) matches the regex pattern.

Instead, you would want to iterate over a sequence of all the attributes in the document, test whether those attributes contain a SQL statement, and then return the element that the matching attribute(s) are attached to.

You could adjust your XQuery FLWOR to:

```
for $x in doc("C:\XXXXX.item")//@*
where matches($x, "INSERT INTO.*"))
return $x/..
```

Or just write as an XPath with predicates:

```
doc("C:\XXXXX.item")//*[@*[ matches(., "INSERT INTO.*")]]
```

The XPath uses the descendant axis `//` to select all elements using the element selector `*`, then the predicate filter evaluates whether any of the element's attributes match the SQL regex by selecting all of the attributes with `@*` and then testing each one with it's own predicate filter. If the predicates select at least one item, then they evaluate to true and the node being tested is selected.

Comment: Hi @Mads Hansen, many thanks for your response! I'm trying to use your code but I'm not getting any results with condition = true()

Comment: There was a typeo in the code that you had posted (was missing the last right paren in the WHERE clause to close the `matches()`, which I had propagated into my answer. I have corrected that and the matches returns a Boolean, so no need to test whether `matches()=true()`. If you remove the WHERE, does it return all the elements that have attributes?

Comment: yes, if I run the for loop without Where clause it returns all the elements

Comment: adjust your regex for the match. You likely want it to be something like "INSERT INTO.*"